# How can I insert code from subclass constructor in superclass constructor?

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, jpanel

So I have this superclass which makes a JPanel with some components. Now I need the subclass to make some radiobuttons and have them displayed before the buttonMin. Now Is my question: how do I call the code from my subclass right there in the superclass where I need it (see code to see where code should be called)?

My superclass

```
public class RecordLine extends JPanel{

    public RecordLine(Product product){
        JTextField fieldName = new JTextField();
        fieldName.setText(product.getName());
        this.add(fieldName);

        Component horizontalStrut = Box.createHorizontalStrut(20);
        this.add(horizontalStrut);

        //Subclass code should be executed here

        Component horizontalStrut_1 = Box.createHorizontalStrut(20);
        this.add(horizontalStrut_1);

        JButton buttonMin = new JButton("-");
        this.add(buttonMin);
    }
}
```

My subclass

```
public class RecordLineDrinks extends RecordLine {

    public RecordLineDrinks(Product product) {
        super(product);

        JRadioButton rdbtnFles = new JRadioButton("Fles");
        this.add(rdbtnFles);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need to change your class structure, providing a method which can be used to create the UI (ie `createView`), from which it can access the other components via getters

This way, you can change the way that `createView` works.

The problem with this is, you will become responsible for re-creating the UI in your subclass completely, hence the reason you will need getter methods for the other UI components.

Another choice is, if you know where you want to add new components, you could provide default implementations of methods which do nothing, but allow sub classes to modify

```
public class RecordLine extends JPanel{

    public RecordLine(Product product){
        JTextField fieldName = new JTextField();
        fieldName.setText(product.getName());
        this.add(fieldName);

        Component horizontalStrut = Box.createHorizontalStrut(20);
        this.add(horizontalStrut);

        //Subclass code should be executed here

        Component horizontalStrut_1 = Box.createHorizontalStrut(20);
        this.add(horizontalStrut_1);

        addBeforeMinButton();

        JButton buttonMin = new JButton("-");
        this.add(buttonMin);
    }

    protected void addBeforeMinButton() {
    }
}
```

But this generally means you know before hand how you might like to modify the UI

Answer (score 0):

you cannot directly... you could make your superclass abstract and then implement a method that you call half way through your constructor

```
public abstract class RecordLine extends JPanel{
    abstract void midwayUpdate();
```

and then

```
public class RecordLineDrinks extends RecordLine {

    public RecordLineDrinks(Product product) {
        super(product);

    }
    void midwayUpdate() {
        JRadioButton rdbtnFles = new JRadioButton("Fles");
        this.add(rdbtnFles);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have a "template method".

Defined in the superclass (but does not necessarily do anything there) and called from the superclass' method.

In the subclass, you can override that method to do things.

```
 //Subclass code should be executed here
 this.addExtraButtons();
```

If you do this in the constructor, you have to be a bit careful though, because it will be called before the instance is completely initalized. Might be cleaner to move all this code into some other `setup()` method.